# OpenCL Less Than Equal and Boolean Vectors

Tags: optimization, opencl

I have a situation that I solved in the following way:

```
//cube_potentials is float8
//level_vec is float8
//shift_vec is int8 and contains (non-overlapping) bit shifts
int8 shifts = (cube_potentials<=level_vec);
int flag_index = 0;\n"
if (shifts.s0) flag_index |= shift_vec.s0;
if (shifts.s1) flag_index |= shift_vec.s1;
if (shifts.s2) flag_index |= shift_vec.s2;
if (shifts.s3) flag_index |= shift_vec.s3;
if (shifts.s4) flag_index |= shift_vec.s4;
if (shifts.s5) flag_index |= shift_vec.s5;
if (shifts.s6) flag_index |= shift_vec.s6;
if (shifts.s7) flag_index |= shift_vec.s7;
```

It works.  The problem is all those if-statements irk me, and I can't imagine they're the fastest thing in the world, either.  I wanted to solve it like so:

```
//Method 1
bool8 less = (bool8)(cube_potentials<=level_vec);
int8 shifts = (int8)(less) * shift_vec;
int flag_index = shifts.s0 | shifts.s1 | shifts.s2 | shifts.s3 | shifts.s4 | shifts.s5 | shifts.s6 | shifts.s7;

//Method 2 (more simply)
int8 shifts = ((int8)(cube_potentials<=level_vec)) * shift_vec;
int flag_index = shifts.s0 | shifts.s1 | shifts.s2 | shifts.s3 | shifts.s4 | shifts.s5 | shifts.s6 | shifts.s7;
```

The problem is that bool8 is a *reserved* type, not a real one, so method 1 is out.  Method 2 doesn't work correctly, though.  I suspect the reason has to do with its first line.  The <= is on two floating point vectors, and I don't know what it returns, but presumably when it is cast to an int8 it isn't all 0s and 1s.

My question is if there is any way to rewrite the original code in a cleaner, more parallel way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.  It might work:

```
// gives -1 (0xFFFFFFFF) or 0 for when T or F for each comparison:
int8 shifts = cube_potentials <= level_vec;

// leaves only the elements that passed the above compare:
shift_vec &= shifts;

// start combining (with all 8 elements):
shift_vec.lo |= shift_vec.hi;

// keep going (down to the bottom 4):
shift_vec.lo.lo |= shift_vec.lo.hi;

// last one (only considering the bottom two):
int flag_index = shift_vec.lo.lo.lo |= shift_vec.lo.lo.hi;
```

Comment: Clever bit twiddling.  I suppose you could also do "-(cube_potentials<=level_vec" and then add everything, but the bitwise and is even better!  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Ok, second attempt:

```
flag_index = dot(shift_vecs, -islessequal(cube_potentials, level_vec));
```

I'd want a good comment around that though.

- `islessequal()` should return -1 or 0 for true and false.
- We negate it to get 1 or 0
- We then use dot product to sum the components in shift_vecs which returned true.

Notes:

- dot() is often a hardware instruction, so should be quick.
- `islessequal()` could be replaced with `<=`
- Only works if `shift_vec` bit values are non-overlapping (you said they were) due to using a summation.